# Is there a document on .rgs files syntax?

Tags: visual-studio, com, atl, rgs

Resource scripts loaded from .rgs files are used with ATL `CComModule::UpdateRegistryFromResource()`. It's quite common to see samples of such files on the net but I've never seen a complete description on what constructs are allowed in .rgs files. Is there such a document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's some [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/understanding-backus-naur-form-bnf-syntax), but it appears to be pretty unfocused.

The book [ATL Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321159624) talks at some length about custom replacements.

Other than that, I haven't seen much...

Comment: MSDN link broken. THis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/atl-registry-component-registrar?view=vs-2017 might be the current version.